# React native can't connect to SSE in android

Tags: react-native

I'm using the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sse

I can't manage to receive events from the server in android even though I copy paste the code from the documentation.

```js
import EventSource from "react-native-sse";

const es = new EventSource("https://your-sse-server.com/.well-known/mercure");

es.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
  console.log("Open SSE connection.");
});

es.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("New message event:", event.data);
});

es.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
  if (event.type === "error") {
    console.error("Connection error:", event.message);
  } else if (event.type === "exception") {
    console.error("Error:", event.message, event.error);
  }
});

es.addEventListener("close", (event) => {
  console.log("Close SSE connection.");
});
```

- react-native: v0.65.1
- react-native-sse: v1.1.0

How can I make it works ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the reason: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2495

> in the reactNativeFlipper.java, the following lines making EventSource (SSE) not working.

#### Solution 1:

- go to `android/app/src/debug/java/com/<projectname>/ReactNativeFlipper.java`
- comment NetworkFlipperPlugin like this:

```java
client.addPlugin(CrashReporterPlugin.getInstance());

// todo commented because of this issue https://github.com/binaryminds/react-native-sse/issues/3 https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2495
//       NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
//       NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
//           new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
//             @Override
//             public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
//               builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
//             }
//           });
//       client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
      client.start();
```

#### Solution 2:

If you don't want to comment the `NetworkFlipperPlugin`.

This bug happen only in debug, so instead of running:

- `react-native run-android`
  You have to run:
- `react-native run-android --variant=release`
  Or simply change it in your `package.json`

```json
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android --variant=release", // here
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I have commented this code out, but it is not working for me. I am trying this in an Expo app. Any idea?

Comment: This fix also works with community implemented fetch which supports streams: https://github.com/react-native-community/fetch

Comment: @FredA got it to work with expo?