# React native app not receiving WebSocket messages on Android

Tags: android, react-native, websocket, expo

I'm creating a react native application using Expo that connects to a WebSocket server to display data from the messages. The code I have works for Web and iOS but for some reason will not work on Android. It looks like the WebSocket connects, but no messages are received.

Here is an expo snack of with the code https://snack.expo.dev/@waddas/cranky-soda.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the TLS connection is failing

Comment: I replaced websocket url with this 'wss://socketsbay.com/wss/v2/1/demo/' in your snack, and its working in android, So the issue must be with websocket from backend.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the app.json file that you have the necessary permissions set.

"android": {
"permissions": [
"INTERNET"
]
}

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69235695/6824121 it might be linked to your problem:

> This is the reason: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2495
>
> > in the reactNativeFlipper.java, the following lines making EventSource (SSE) not working.
>
> #### Solution 1:
>
> - go to `android/app/src/debug/java/com/<projectname>/ReactNativeFlipper.java`
> - comment NetworkFlipperPlugin like this:
>
> ```java
> client.addPlugin(CrashReporterPlugin.getInstance());
>
> // todo commented because of this issue https://github.com/binaryminds/react-native-sse/issues/3 https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2495
> //       NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
> //       NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
> //           new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
> //             @Override
> //             public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
> //               builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
> //             }
> //           });
> //       client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
>       client.start();
> ```
>
> #### Solution 2: If you don't want to comment the `NetworkFlipperPlugin`.
>
> This bug happen only in debug, so instead of running:
>
> - `react-native run-android` You have to run:
> - `react-native run-android --variant=release` Or simply change it in your `package.json` `json {   // ...   "scripts": { "android": "react-native run-android --variant=release", // here "ios": "react-native run-ios", "start": "react-native start", "test": "jest", "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"   },   // ... }`